# Google indexing how to

Tags: search

How do you get google to index like in the image below. Is this a function of the crawler or can you manipulate google to disply your site this way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the crawler to recognize your [sitelinks](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?&answer=47334), but theres not garantuee hat they show up on the searchresults. In fact on most sites they don't.

Here's how to get your sitelinks crawled (from the webmaster tools page):

- On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
- Under Site configuration, click Sitelinks.
- In the For this search result box, complete the URL for which you don't want a specific sitelink URL to appear. ([How to find the right URL.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=63758))
- In the Demote this sitelink URL box, complete the URL of the sitelink you want to demote.

Answer (score 0):

These are called Sitelinks, and they are auto generated by Google.

From the Webmaster Tools dashboard in Google:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334